# Moveit Setup Assistant cant locate all meshes

Tags: ros, urdf, ros-melodic, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @ all,
I created a package in a new workspace. Inside this package I have an URDF Folder with my xacro for the robot.
The URDF uses package:// to locate the meshes:

```
<mesh filename="package://motoman_es200/meshes/visual/es200_base_lowres.dae"/>
```

The strange thing is:
The es200_base_lowres.dae is found and viewed in Rviz (moveit setup)
But the following meshes not.

```
<mesh filename="package://motoman_es200/meshes/visual/es200_saxis_lowres.dae"/>
```

Output (snipped):

```
Error retrieving file [file:///home/harry/xs_robot/src/motoman_es200/meshes/collision/es200_saxis_lowres.dae]:
Couldn't open file /home/harry/xs_robot/src/motoman_es200/meshes/collision/es200_saxis_lowres.dae
```

Rospack finds my package

This is strange, maybe you can point me to the right direction.
R/W Rights are all the same.

Cheers, Harry.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317767/moveit-setup-assistant-cant-locate-all-meshes/) by [Harry XS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40357/harry-xs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-03-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:
Btw: depending on the specific variant of the ES 200 that you have there, perhaps [ros-industrial/motoman_experimental#28](https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman_experimental/pull/28) is interesting.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:
Hm, actually: what is the output of:

```
ls -al /home/harry/xs_robot/src/motoman_es200/meshes/collision/es200_saxis_lowres.dae
```

**Comment by [Harry XS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40357/harry-xs/) on 2019-03-06**:
Oh, wow. Seems to be OS related, it cant be found:

ls -al /home/harry/xs_robot/src/motoman_es200/meshes/collision/es200_saxis_lowres.dae
ls: Zugriff auf '/home/harry/xs_robot/src/motoman_es200/meshes/collision/es200_saxis_lowres.dae' nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:
Is the path perhaps simply incorrect?

**Comment by [Harry XS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40357/harry-xs/) on 2019-03-06**:
Nice find, thank you and thank you for the new motoman_experimental es200 link.
Cheers, Harry.

**Comment by [Harry XS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40357/harry-xs/) on 2019-03-06**:
No, its ok and there...

```
~/xs_robot/src/motoman_es200/meshes/collision$ ls
es200_base_lowres.dae  es200_baxis_lores.dae  es200_laxis_lores.dae  es200_raxis_lores.dae  es200_saxis_lores.dae  es200_taxis_lores.dae  es200_uaxis_lores.dae
```

**Comment by [Harry XS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40357/harry-xs/) on 2019-03-06**:
I'll close it, since its not ROS related. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> No, its ok and there...

> ```
> ~/xs_robot/src/motoman_es200/meshes/collision$ ls
> ```

```
es200_base_lowres.dae  es200_baxis_lores.dae  es200_laxis_lores.dae  es200_raxis_lores.dae  es200_saxis_lores.dae  es200_taxis_lores.dae  es200_uaxis_lores.dae
```

I see `es200_saxis_lores.dae` in this listing, while the URI you spec is:

```
package://motoman_es200/meshes/visual/es200_saxis_lowres.dae
```

Note the extra `w` in `lowres` vs the `lores` in the actual filename.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Harry XS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40357/harry-xs/) on 2019-03-06**:
Oh my God, thank you....sometimes we go blind. I need a coffee.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:
Sometimes :)

Would you be interested in contributing your ES200 model to `motoman_experimental`?

**Comment by [Harry XS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40357/harry-xs/) on 2019-03-09**:
I would, but actually the ES200-RDII is exactly the same Robot imo like the ES 165-RDII in this package. It just can carry 200kg instead of165 kg, and it is a bit slower...So yes, I can do it when everything works. Thank you again.